# How select data in postgresql using ' where' array string element from jsonb fields?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, where-clause

[image]

i have table like above . i want to select the  **pengumuman** field from table using one of
element in array  from **office** field . `SELECT pengumuman from pengumuman_table where officee ...`  and i don't know what the next to get data from array with element BWI . how fix that query ? .thanks for your replay

Answer (score 2):

If you want to search the array for a specific value, use `any()`:

```
select pengumuman
from pengumuman_table
where $1 = any(office)
```

`$1` is the parameter to the query, a literal string to search for in the text arrays.

Comment: hi thank's for your replay ..when i try that query i got ``` SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "bwi" does not exist¶  Position: 39```

Comment: @silvesterlanduhungguwali: there is no `bwi` in this query. You would need to figure out what the correct column names are...